# correct policy to get secrets on local go app

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

playing with a small project on AWS:

- golang app
- RDS/MySQL database
- secret manager
- API gateway and lambda

I'm running the go app locally to verify the interaction with the database, but I can't get it to work with the secret manager.

using this sample code:

```
func getCreds() {
    config, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion(region))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    svc := secretsmanager.NewFromConfig(config)
    input := &secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
        SecretId:     aws.String(secretName),
        VersionStage: aws.String("AWSCURRENT"),
    }

    result, err := svc.GetSecretValue(context.TODO(), input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    var secretString string = *result.SecretString
    log.Printf("pwd: %s", secretString)
}
```

I'm getting

```
operation error Secrets Manager: GetSecretValue, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, failed to sign request: failed to retrieve credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds
```

If I understand correctly, I need to add a permission to a user/policy. But where to add this? In the IAM console? Or the secret manager console?

And what should it be?

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "<what to add here>"},
            "Resource": "<and here>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Go Application doesn't find the credentials to use the AWS API.

According [to (Configuring Credentials)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/) you can use this code to automagically use `~/.aws/config` for credentials locally

```
sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
}))
```

if you supply a custom config, the credentials must be supplied. There are other methods, pick one that suits you. [AWS proposes the method above](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html).

This covers running with your users. For AWS execution you need to give the Lambda function access to the secret:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:111122223333:secret:aes128-1a2b3c"
            ]
        }
}
```

The above policy must be applied to the IAM Role the Lambda is executed with. You can find the role AWS Console -> Lambda -> You Lambda -> Configuration -> Permissions -> Execution Role

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The last missing piece was adding an endpoint to the VPC https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-to-aws-secrets-manager-service-within-a-virtual-private-cloud/#:~:text=Open%20the%20Amazon%20VPC%20console,Manager%20endpoint%20service%20named%20com.

Comment: True. If lambdas are not connected to VPCs, they have internet access and can access the secrets manager. If they are put into a VPC, they adhere to the VPC networking. If internet access is missing, you need an interface endpoint for all AWS services you are trying to connect (including SM).